# A prove using Hilbert System

Tags: logic

I need to prove, using the Hilbert System: $(\neg A → \neg B) → ((\neg B → A) → B)$

The Axioms are:

1. $A→(B→ A)$
2. $(A→(B → C)) → ((A→ B)→ (A→ C))$
3. $(\neg A → \neg B) → (B → A)$

   MP: $\dfrac{A, A→ B}{B}$

Any idea?

Comment: neg A -> neg B |- (B -> A) \ neg A -> neg B, B |- A \ neg A -> neg B, B |- B->(A->B)

Comment: now it should be correct

Comment: Okay, *now* we've got something to start with. You should insert it in your question, it's better to see your attempt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm stuck with the last step, I don't know if I can leave it as it:

4.$(\neg A\rightarrow \neg B)$hypothesis

5.$(B\rightarrow A)$ MP(3,4)

6.$(B\rightarrow A)\rightarrow (\neg B \rightarrow (B\rightarrow A) )$ applying Axiom 1

7.$(\neg B \rightarrow (B\rightarrow A) )$ MP(1,4)

8.$(\neg B \rightarrow (B\rightarrow A) )\rightarrow ((\neg B \rightarrow B) \rightarrow (\neg B \rightarrow A)) $ Applying axiom 2

9.$(\neg B \rightarrow B) \rightarrow (\neg B \rightarrow A) $ MP(7,8)

10.$(\neg B \rightarrow A) $ because it is a tautology

... Stuck

Comment: (neg B -> B) -> B is because a tautology. Thanks. I have seen this tautology before. The problem is now to prove it. But it is a other question. Thanks

Comment: Thear are a mistake in 8. It is (¬B→(B→A))→((¬B→B)→(¬B→A))

Comment: Yep, thanks. Taken into account.

Comment: Thanks for the help. but now the result don't get the indicated result

Comment: No problem, I hope you will be able to find it yourself!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% certain, but I think that in a calculus with these axioms the fact that the substitution $(\lnot T \to \lnot F) \to ((\lnot F \to T) \to F)$ (where $T$ stands for True and $F$ for False) results in the formula being invalidated means that it cannot be deduced.

Comment: Indeed. $(\neg A\to\neg B)\to((\neg B\to A)\to B)$ is not a tautology.  However, $(\neg A\to\neg B)\to((\neg B\to A)\to A)$ is, so that is *possibly* what the OP was trying to prove. .